# ORGANIZAR DATOS JSON

Tags: c#

Consumo la siguiente API

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //OBTENER VEHICULOS

        int r = 51795;
        var client = new RestClient($"https://fleet.cloudfleet.com/api/v1/vehicles?id={r}");
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KEY"]);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        var res =   client;
        Root ob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(Convert.ToString(res));
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Que meda respuesta con lo siguiente

> {"id":51795,"code":"GSF850","typeName":"Tractocamion","brandName":"nn","lineName":"T
> 800","odometerType":1,"mainMeasurementType":1,"year":null,"color":null,"mainFuelType":"ACPM","auxFuelType":null,"workload":"medium","maxOdometerDay":260.0000,"avgOdometerDay":150.0000,"maxHourmeterDay":null,"avgHourmeterDay":null,"city":null,"costCenter":null,"group1":null,"group2":null,"commentGroupingData":null,"auxCode":null,"vin":null,"imeiGps":null,"owner":null,"engine":null,"weightCapacity":null,"chassisNumber":null,"serialNumber":null,"purchaseDate":null,"purchaseOdometer":null,"purchaseHourmeter":null,"purchasePrice":null,"seller":null,"subaccountQty":1,"driver":null,"createdAt":"2014-03-21T19:28:25.1500000Z","createdBy":{"id":19718,"name":"Juan
> Perez"}}

Como puedo ir yo organizando estos datos para ponerlos en variables, sacar los campos y los valores que me devuelve para utilizarlos

**Lo que llevo**

```
  int r = 51795;
        var client = new RestClient($"https://fleet.cloudfleet.com/api/v1/vehicles?id={r}");
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KEY"]);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        var res =   client;
        Root ob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(Convert.ToString(res));
        Console.Read();
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string typeName { get; set; }
        public string brandName { get; set; }
        public string lineName { get; set; }
        public int odometerType { get; set; }
        public int mainMeasurementType { get; set; }
        public object year { get; set; }
        public object color { get; set; }
        public string mainFuelType { get; set; }
        public object auxFuelType { get; set; }
        public string workload { get; set; }
        public double maxOdometerDay { get; set; }
        public double avgOdometerDay { get; set; }
        public object maxHourmeterDay { get; set; }
        public object avgHourmeterDay { get; set; }
        public object city { get; set; }
        public object costCenter { get; set; }
        public object group1 { get; set; }
        public object group2 { get; set; }
        public object commentGroupingData { get; set; }
        public object auxCode { get; set; }
        public object vin { get; set; }
        public object imeiGps { get; set; }
        public object owner { get; set; }
        public object engine { get; set; }
        public object weightCapacity { get; set; }
        public object chassisNumber { get; set; }
        public object serialNumber { get; set; }
        public object purchaseDate { get; set; }
        public object purchaseOdometer { get; set; }
        public object purchaseHourmeter { get; set; }
        public object purchasePrice { get; set; }
        public object seller { get; set; }
        public int subaccountQty { get; set; }
        public object driver { get; set; }
        public DateTime createdAt { get; set; }
        public CreatedBy createdBy { get; set; }
    }



    public class CreatedBy
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: El Json está incompleto. Por otro lado. ¿Has intentado algo?

Comment: Si falta otros datos pero son completamente iguales estoy tratando de hacer esto  serializar y deserializar (marshal y unmarshal) JSON en .NET  pero es que nunca lo he hecho

Comment: No es por ser mala onda, en el sitio hay una buena cantidad de preguntas de donde puedes aprender, mira este enlace https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+json y revisa algunas, tienen código de ejemplo de diversos escenarios, con ello puedes intentar realizar algo y una vez que intentes verás que no es tan complicado, si todavía falta algo después del intento (que debería estar incluido en la pregunta), cuenta con mi apoyo :D

Comment: Mira lo que hice cuando investigue cree los objetos y lo Deserialize

Comment: ¡Perfecto! Ahora, me parece que ya tienes todo prácticamente solucionado, ¿cuál es el escenario que tienes?

Comment: Me sale  el siguiente error--> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: R. Path '', line 0, position 0.'

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117281/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-esteban-giraldo).

Comment: ¿Te parece si agregas la respuesta que lograste durante la conversación en el chat y la marcas como aceptada (en 24 horas) para mantener el orden en el sitio y de paso logras ser el héroe de más desarrolladores :D ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   int r = 51795;
    var client = new restclient($"https://fleet.cloudfleet.com/api/v1/vehicles?id={r}");
    client.timeout = -1;
    var request = new restrequest(method.get);
    request.addheader("authorization", configurationmanager.appsettings["key"]);
    request.addheader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    irestresponse response = client.execute(request);
    messagebox.show(response.content);
    //Así desrealizo la respuesta  
    modelos ob = jsonconvert.deserializeobject<modelos>(response.content);
    //Dentro de un datagridview si el api me de vuelve lista
    datagridview1.rows.add(ob);
    //Obtengo los datos si los quiero mostrar o trabajar con ellos
    lblvalorplaca.text = ob.code;
```

Comment: Edita la respuesta, incluye tu clase "modelos", ya estás habilitado para marcar esta respuesta como aceptada (click en el check del costado). Saludos

Comment: Me parece perfecto que aceptes la respuesta, incluye lo demás, de ese modo serás el héroe de más usuarios que estén pasando por el mismo escenario. Saludos.